# Replace two values in a list using list comprehension?

Tags: python

I have thw following list:

```
list1 = ["cmd_%Y","cmd_%y","cmd_other"]
```

I need to replace `"%y"` and `"%Y"` (uppercase and lowercase) using list comprehensions, I tried just for one substr:

```
list1 = [ cmd.replace('%Y', "some_val_forY") for cmd in list1 ]
```

And obviously I'm discarding non-pythonic way to solve this issue.

How can I modify my solution to acept both criteria and get:

```
list1 = [ "cmd_some_val_for_Y","cmd_some_val_for_y", "cmd_other" ]
```

Comment: So you want to get the first `Y` in uppercase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most simple case - with *chained* replacement:

```
list1 = ["cmd_%Y","cmd_%y","cmd_other"]
list1 = [cmd.replace('%Y', "some_val_Y").replace('%y', "some_val_y") for cmd in list1]
print(list1)   # ['cmd_some_val_Y', 'cmd_some_val_y', 'cmd_other']
```

Otherwise, use regex substitution:

```
import re

list1 = ["cmd_%Y","cmd_%y","cmd_other"]
pat = re.compile(r'%y', re.I)
list1 = [pat.sub(lambda m: 'some_val_y' if m.group() == '%y' else 'some_val_Y', cmd) 
         for cmd in list1]

print(list1)   # ['cmd_some_val_Y', 'cmd_some_val_y', 'cmd_other']
```